# Is there a way in which to show two values per pie slice in a pie chart?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Trying to show for each major slice of a pie chart(4 total slices), two pieces of data per pie slice (% of items with information and % of items without information)

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of what you have? It may help make it a little more clear about what you want? The way I am interpreting it, you have a 4 slice pie but you want to consolidate it to two slices by putting the 4 slices into two groups?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. what I am doing is this.  I have 4 regions/divisions - call them A,B,C and D (these are the 4 pieces of the total pie) each region has items that are in two categories - items with serial numbers and items without serial numbers. I am trying to show in each region/division pie slice - both pieces of information.For example if Region A has 40% items with  info and 60% items without (that is reflected in region A slice of the pie)  - then the same for the other 3 regions with their breakdown of items.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that excel can do exactly what you're thinking of. You can create sub pie-charts as shown [on this page](http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1442-excel-create-pie-of-pie-chart.html), but it might be better to create one pie chart with 8 pieces of data, or have a larger pie chart with 4 sections, and then 4 smaller charts.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this just once, you could paste values, then use Alt+Enter when typing in the Category names to put a line break in your labels.

[image: pie]